# How to access a variable in an EJS file from a linked JS file

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am currently working on one of my first web applications and I am having difficulties accessing a variable on a JS file linked to an EJS file. I apologize in advance if I describe my situation incorrectly or if I am making a stupid mistake as I am very new to web development.

So basically I am attempting to create a real estate website that has similar functionality to Zillow, in which you can search for a property on a home page and then the website will redirect you to a browse page which contains a map with a variety of properties which match the user's search. I currently have the home page and browse page set up successfully. The user inputs a search term, and then my express server redirects the user to the browse page. When the browse page loads, I have a linked JS file to the browse EJS file which successfully connects to all the required APIs and loads the map. However, what I'm having trouble with is accessing some of the variables from JS file after the map has been populated. For example, on the JS file I specify propertyCount = 30, yet I cannot access the propertyCount on the EJS file.

So as of right now, I can successfully inject a user search term from the home page by including the search query in the res.redirect, and I can successfully run a JS code linked to my EJS file to create the map. However I cannot access any of the variable from that file after the code has ran.

I attached a small snippet of my code below to help display what I am explaining. I want to pull propertyCount from the searchProperties.js file, but I am getting a "propertyCount is not defined" error. I attempted to inject it directly into the ejs code similar to the searchQuery, but it did not work.

```
<table>
    <% for(let i=0; i < propertyCount; i++) { %>
       <tr>
         <td><%= "property" %></td>
         <td><%= i %></td>
       </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>


<script>
    const searchQuery = '<%=searchQuery%>'
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="/public/searchProperties.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

In that case, within the forloop, add the .length property and see what that will return.